# Spring security ROLE_USER from Tables

Tags: java, spring, jsf, spring-security

I'm involve in JSF+Spring security project

Here I saw this code fragment

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login" />
</http>
```

can we use Users from tables **instead of use hardcode ROLE_USER in config.xml like above**.?

can we use method in there.?
access="method()" then what it need to return.?
boolean or view.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define users and roles in the database, you first need to create a custom [UserDetailsService](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.M1/reference/htmlsingle/#core-services-jdbc-user-service) accessing the database. Than you need to create the neccessary tables form the [sql schema](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.M1/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-schema) in the docs. For the access part you should use the [expression language](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.M1/reference/htmlsingle/#el-access).